# Spelling error in context.xml causes another error

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi, connection-pooling

I've a web application with database data source defined in META-INF/context.xml.

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/MYJNDI"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="Arash"
              password="who"
              driverClassNmae="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
              maxActive="10"
              maxIdle="1"/>

</Context>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <resource-ref>
        <description>Oracel + jndi test</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/MYJNDI</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

and The problem is I get following exception when I run this code:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/MYJNDI");
**connection = ds.getConnection();**
```

Exception :
***Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe'***

Comment: The `context.xml` has an error. The `driverClassName` is miss spelled.  Did you copy-paste the real file?

Comment: Was true
Thank you ...............

Comment: Did you really just post a question for help to check your syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `context.xml` has an error.

The `driverClassName` is miss spelled.